# String Manipulation in PostgreSQL

Tags: string, postgresql

since am new database development my question may very basic.

How to get a output like below in `PostgreSQL`

```
 outputString
 ------------
 a
 aa
 aaa
 aaaa
 aaaaa
 aaaaaa
 aaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaa
```

- the total rows returned should be 10

Comment: is that a _home work_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it using  [**WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html)

```
WITH RECURSIVE source (outputString) AS (
SELECT 'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT outputString || 'a'
FROM source
WHERE length(outputString) < 10
)
SELECT * FROM source;
```

[Click here and read  to get more details about CTEs](http://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/cte.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

[`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) can be used to create a series of numbers. Once you have that, you can use [`lpad`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) to create that many `'a'`s:

```
SELECT LPAD('', GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10), 'a')
```